# Identifying Duplicates

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I apologize if this is worded poorly but I'm not 100% clear on how to word the idea that's going on in my head. Here goes:

I have a table with several columns but here are the three in question: **contactID**, **primaryID**, and **Address**

This table contains contact information, name, address, phone number, etc. There are several rows that are unique in every way except they contain the same **Address**. *These rows are essentially contacts (or sub-contacts) of other contacts. These are uniquely identified by a 4th column called **TypeNum** and a second table that contains a SecondaryID. (This info isn't actually important but might help explain why I want to what I'm about to ask*

Some of the contacts are currently sitting as Parents and SHOULD have a SecondaryID. If I have three contacts, I want to assign two of them a primaryID equal to the contactID of the third. I don't necessarily care which two get the primaryID.

Is there any conceivable way to do this?

**Edit:** I added an example image below. I'd like to make **primaryID** for the second and third rows equal to the **contactID** for the first row. *(It doesn't actually matter which two get the **contactID**, as long as its 2/3 and the 2 get the contactID of the 3rd).*

**Edit:** It would also work if I could update all the duplicates primaryID with the contactID of one of the duplicates.

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: That's complicated. Can you provide data example and possible include a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) as well?

Comment: Maybe add some sample data and expected results - I'm not sure, having read your description, what you actually want to do. (Please try to give a few examples rather than just focus on one specific set of duplicates)

Comment: There is no Address in the image.

Comment: Address = Line1 (I apologize for not using the correct column name): Line1 is supposed to be the first line of an address (e.g. Street Name/Number) but in many cases the users put real names or have omitted parts of the Street Name (e.g. St., Rd., Ave.,).

Answer (score 1):

This query first finds `contacts` that have three or more entries with the same `address` by using `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3`.

It also takes a `contactID` from this set of duplicates, by using `MIN(ContactID)`.  This `contactID` is then assigned to each `PrimaryID` for all the duplicates in this set, except for the duplicate that has the `ContactID` equal to `MinContactID`:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.PrimaryID = dups.MinContactID
FROM
    Contacts c 
    JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(ContactID) AS MinContactID, Address
        FROM Contacts
        GROUP BY Address
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
    ) dups ON c.Address = dups.Address AND c.ContactID <> dups.MinContactID
```

Comment: But won't the c.ContactID <> dups.MinContactID will exclude the parent.

Comment: @Blam Maybe I misunderstood the requirements.  I understood it as all but one of the records should have their `PrimaryID` set...

Comment: Yes, all but 1 record should have the primaryID set. If I were to eliminate these duplicates based on whether or not they have a primaryID, I'd be removing all of the unless one DIDN'T get the ID. (I don't plan on doing that but you get the idea).

Comment: @AGx-07_162 So does this query solve your problem? If not, why?

Comment: I can agree with that interpretation +1